# Bounds for Dedekind Zeta functions

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, we denote $\zeta_K(s)$ by the corresponding Dedekind zeta function. For a complex number $s$, we denote $\sigma, \tau$ by its real and imaginary parts respectively.

**Question 1.**  Can we find positive constants $c,d$ such that for $|\tau|\geq d$  and $\sigma\geq 1-c/ \log |\tau|$, we have

1. $\zeta_K'(s)/\zeta_K(s)\ll \log|\tau|$;
2. $1/\zeta_K(s)\ll \log |\tau|$;
3. $|\log\zeta_K(s)|\ll \log\log|\tau|+O(1)$.

When $K=\mathbb{Q}$, the above assertion is classical, cf. Theorem 3.22 of [Tenenbaum's book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=UEk-CgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=tenenbaum%20analytic%20number%20theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi12vKri5zbAhXIuhQKHTeeCjIQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=tenenbaum%20analytic%20number%20theory&f=false). I guess similar inequalities hold for all Dedekind zeta functions, and the proof should follow the similar methods, but I am not able to find a desired theorem or proof in the literature.

So could you please give me a reference? Thanks a lot!